# Scrapy:at 0 items/min

Tags: python, scrapy

I get a Scrapy example from a website,it works but seems something wrong:it can not get all the content,and I don't know what happened.
  The example uses Scrapy+Redis+MongoDB.

the info:

```
2015-10-09 01:43:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 292 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 291 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:44:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:45:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:46:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:47:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:48:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:49:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:50:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:51:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:52:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:53:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:54:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:55:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:56:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:57:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-09 01:58:33 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 292 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 291 items (at 0 items/min)
```

novspider.py

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-

from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from novelspider.items import NovelspiderItem
import re

class novSpider(RedisSpider):
    name = "novspider"
    redis_key = 'nvospider:start_urls'
    start_urls = ['http://www.daomubiji.com/']                               

    def parse(self,response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        table = selector.xpath('//table')
        for each in table:
            bookName = each.xpath('tr/td[@colspan="3"]/center/h2/text()').extract()[0]
            content = each.xpath('tr/td/a/text()').extract()
            url = each.xpath('tr/td/a/@href').extract()
            for i in range(len(url)):
                item = NovelspiderItem()
                item['bookName'] = bookName
                item['chapterURL'] = url[i]

                try:
                    item['bookTitle'] = content[i].split(' ')[0]
                    item['chapterNum'] = content[i].split(' ')[1]
                except Exception,e:
                    continue

                try:
                    item['chapterName'] = content[i].split(' ')[2]
                except Exception,e:
                    item['chapterName'] = content[i].split(' ')[1][-3:]
                yield Request(url[i], callback='parseContent', meta={'item':item})

    def parseContent(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        html = selector.xpath('//div[@class="content"]').extract()[0]
        textField = re.search('<div style="clear:both"></div>(.*?)<div', html,re.S).group(1)
        text = re.findall('<p>(.*?)</p>',textField,re.S)
        fulltext = ''
        for each in text:
            fulltext += each
        item['text'] = fulltext
        yield item
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for novelspider project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
# default. All the other settings are documented here:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#

BOT_NAME = 'novelspider'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['novelspider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'novelspider.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['novelspider.pipelines.NovelspiderPipeline']

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.54 Safari/536.5'
COOKIES_ENABLED = True

SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler"
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = True
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.SpiderPriorityQueue'
REDIS_URL = None
REDIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REDIS_PORT = 6379

MONGODB_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DBNAME = 'novdata'
MONGODB_DOCNAME = 'nov1'
```

pipelines.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
from items import NovelspiderItem 
from scrapy.conf import settings
import pymongo

class NovelspiderPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        host = settings['MONGODB_HOST']
        port = settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        dbName = settings['MONGODB_DBNAME']
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
        tdb = client[dbName]
        self.post = tdb[settings['MONGODB_DOCNAME']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        bookInfo = dict(item)
        self.post.insert(bookInfo)
        return item
```

items.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

from scrapy import Field, Item


class NovelspiderItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    bookName = Field()
    bookTitle = Field()
    chapterNum = Field()
    chapterName = Field()
    chapterURL = Field()
    text = Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reach the parse method that way. Use this instead:

```py
yield Request(
    url[i], 
    callback=self.parseContent, # <--
    meta={'item':item})
```